# JWT authorization & authentication

Tags: node.js, sql-server, api, rest, jwt

Basically I’m building a REST api to act as an intermediary between the DB and the other different applications, is it possible to use JWT to post users to the Microsoft Sql server and also add authorization to check with DB if the user credentials are correct or not. I searched the internet for tutorials but I can’t find one.

Comment: what was your `search query`?

Comment: Jwt with Microsoft sql server, correct me if it’s wrong

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=Jwt+with+Microsoft+sql+serve

Comment: All tutorials comes with mongoose I didn’t find one tutorial with Mssql

Answer (score 0):

yes, jwt can be used along with any db. you can check the following tutorial for sql
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uvy_BlgwfLI .

for jwt with mongoose (
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2jqok-WgelI
)

Comment: That’s a good tutorial but it doesn’t show the authentication and authorization process

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @MohammedAlqahtani , authentication and authorization will be same as in other mongoose tutorial, just reading data from the db will be different